# Javascript: detect usage of Element.innerHTML and / or Element.outerHTML in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, detect

Writing a sort of polyfill for legacy browsers, I need a way to detect usage of `Element.innerHTML` and / or `Element.outerHTML` in IE8.

Something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElem'),
    currentHTML = elem.innerHTML;

elem.innerHTML = 'Some valid HTML markup';

// a way to detect this
if (currentHTML !== elem.innerHTML) {
  alert(elem + ' changed it\'s HTML')
}
```

As `Element.prototype.appendChild` is a method that can be easily changed to serve my purpose, I don't know if there is anything to do for `innerHTML`/`outerHTML` in IE8, ideas?

Comment: The best you can do is watch the element with an interval timer probably.

Comment: That's too much to ask from a legacy browser like IE8. Anything else?

Comment: Nope. IE didn't have anything like property observers.